# How to assign a function reference to a variable?

Tags: php, function, lambda

I would like to handle functions references and lambda in consistent way in PHP, but I have trouble when assigning a function reference to a variable.

```
function foo()
{
  echo "hi\n";
}

$here = function() { echo "hello\n"; };
$here = foo;
```

The last line gives me a warning. I could use string literal, but I am afraid of two things -- using it later as string by mistake, and problems with name resolution when passing such string-reference over namespace boundaries.

Is there any way to grab that reference without using strings?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to create it as an anonymous function:

```
$foo = function()
{
  echo "hi\n";
};

$foo();
```

Comment: Thank you for that approach, however the price is high -- you have to rewrite all the functions which could be referenced.